# Remove decimal values from the axis

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I'm using google charts and I have an issue with formatting of the hAxis.
It looks like this when there are only 4 values on it:

[image]

I want to remove those decimal numbers between the real values. I don't want it to show 0.5,1.5,2.5,3.5
How can it be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are a few options that could be used, if you were using a *classic* chart
but those are not supported using *material* charts

you can use option `hAxis.format` to change the number format,
but this will only remove the decimal and cause the numbers to repeat

the only method i've found when using a *matieral* chart,
is to use string values for the x-axis...

```
['Lesson', 'Average', 'Average best'],
['1', 10, 10],
['2', 10, 10],
['3', 10, 10],
['4', 7, 7.5]
```

or you can use a `DataView` to convert the numbers to strings...

```
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
  ['Lesson', 'Average', 'Average best'],
  [1, 10, 10],
  [2, 10, 10],
  [3, 10, 10],
  [4, 7, 7.5]
]);

var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
view.setColumns([{
  calc: function (dt, row) {
    return dt.getValue(row, 0).toFixed(0);
  },
  label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
  type: 'string'
}, 1, 2]);
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['bar']
}).then(function () {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Lesson', 'Average', 'Average best'],
    [1, 10, 10],
    [2, 10, 10],
    [3, 10, 10],
    [4, 7, 7.5]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([{
    calc: function (dt, row) {
      return dt.getValue(row, 0).toFixed(0);
    },
    label: data.getColumnLabel(0),
    type: 'string'
  }, 1, 2]);

  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Results distribution by lesson',
    },
    height: 280
  };

  var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(view, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you!! I've just added the 'var view' part to my code and it works exactly as I need.